# AlertDialog accesible desde cualquier pantalla de la aplicacion

Tags: flutter

He definido una clase llamada Utils en la cual he colocado funciones de uso común en las pantallas, dentro de esa clase tengo una función que me retorna un Widget showDialog.

```
class Utils { 
   Future<bool> customOnWillPop(BuildContext context) async {
     return showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text(labelOut),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                child: new Text(labelRefuse)),
            new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => exit(0), child: new Text(labelAccept))
          ],
        )) ??
    false; 
  }
}
```

Al momento de llamarlo desde una screen me genera el siguiente error:

**The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future Function()'.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:demo/Util/utils.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}



class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
   Utils _utils = new Utils();
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return (new WillPopScope(
           onWillPop: Utils().customOnWillPop(context),
           child: new Scaffold()
      ));
   }
}
```

Alguna idea de como solucionar este error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error dice que no puedes asignar un `Future` a un parámetro que espera `Future Function()`

### Solución:

Puedes crear una función anónima que ejecute `Utils().customOnWillPop`

#### Ejemplo:

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  Utils _utils = new Utils();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _utils.customOnWillPop(context),
      child: Scaffold(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, funcionó a la perfección.